# iOS Cocoalumberjack: ThreadId and ProcessId not printed in File Logger but prints in TTY Console logs

Tags: ios, swift, cocoalumberjack

I have created TestProject in Swift and added Cocoalumberjack using CocoaPod. Initialized Cocoalumberjack logger to add logs to console and file. Please find the initializer code snippet below.

```
    DDLog.add(DDTTYLogger.sharedInstance, with: DDLogLevel.verbose) // TTY = Xcode console

    let fileLogger: DDFileLogger = DDFileLogger() // File Logger
    fileLogger.rollingFrequency = 60 * 60 * 24 // 24 hours
    fileLogger.logFileManager.maximumNumberOfLogFiles = 7
    DDLog.add(fileLogger)
```

When i printed test message, Thread id and process id is missing in logs added in file but present in console.

```
DDLogDebug("Test message")
```

> **Console log**: 2019-03-03 13:28:00:427 TestProject[`81343:2525521`] Test message
>
> **File Log**: 2019/03/03 13:28:00:427  Test message

I need thread id and process id (81343:2525521) also to be added in file logs. 
Could someone help me in fixing this?

Cocoapod version : 1.5.3

Cocoalumberjack: CocoaLumberjack/Swift (3.4.2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a custom format for it. Here a sample for threadID and timestamp

```
class MyCustom: NSObject, DDLogFormatter { 
    func format(message logMessage: DDLogMessage) -> String? { 
       return "\(logMessage.threadID) - \(logMessage.timestamp)" 
    } 
}
```

Then adding to your file logger: 
    `fileLogger.logFormatter = MyCustom()`

Comment: Thanks @donmichael. I removed level as you suggested. But still issue is not resolved.

Comment: Could you show the code how you log `thread id and process id `

Comment: Thread id and process is logged by Cocoalumberjack. This is the code to print test message. "DDLogDebug("Test message")".  It prints these id's in console alone but not in file.

Comment: Okay, I understood now. You need a custom format for it. Here a sample for `threadID` and `timestamp`


`class MyCustom: NSObject, DDLogFormatter {
    func format(message logMessage: DDLogMessage) -> String? {
        return  "\(logMessage.threadID) - \(logMessage.timestamp)"
    }
}`

Then adding to your file logger: `fileLogger.logFormatter = MyCustom()`

Comment: Btw, in here you could find the whole information related to the log message: information related to the log message including: https://github.com/CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack/blob/master/Documentation/CustomFormatters.md

Comment: thanks @donmicael. DDLogFormatter did the magic. I am able to print the thread id in the file logger. Please post ur solution in the answer section instead of in comments.

Comment: Great to hear that mate.